# Memory leak issue in iPhone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am a beginner in iPhone programming. When running my app in iPhone, I am getting the error as terminate called after throwing an instance of `NSException`. Program received signal:  `SIGABRT`. Can anyone please help me out to solve this issue?

Comment: You'll need to post the section of your code that's causing the crash before anyone is likely to be able to help you debug it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a memory leak issue, there is some error causing your application to crash.

In XCode, run the app in debug mode, so when it crashes, before terminating, it will let you debug (with gdb, on  the console). Try the command "bt" (short for backtrace), which will show the stack trace of where the crash happen.

Comment: It is common to the error happen inside a call to the API, check the backtrace and find which part of your code made the call which crashed. You can use the command "up #" (where # is a number) to go up in the stack.